# Is this piece some kind of rare/modified 200?

Tags: part-identification, motor

I have this piece which vaguely resembles [200, Technic Rack Winder Axle](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=200) ([Rebricked](http://rebrickable.com/parts/200)) but one end is different. It is 5 studs long, axle is 1 stud long, the gear lies between 3rd and 4th stud and the axle hole is approximately 1 stud deep.

There is no branding on the piece so I am not sure if it isn't something other than Lego.

[image]

**Edit:** The axle hole holds axles really tight, but the axle end doesn't hold other things too well. As for the gear teeth, they are exactly the same as in [3647](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=3647) (the same shape number and size), although they are slightly moved, 10 degrees or maybe even less.

As mentioned it *is* possible it's not Lego, but I personally don't recall ever buying any technic-like non-Lego sets. Can't vouch for my brothers after who I've inherited most of my collection.

Comment: Looks to me like the bits of plastic you get inside a pen, that make it click...

Comment: @ACarter I've dismantled a lot of pens in my life and they've all looked a bit different, not to mention that any axle fits perfectly in the axle hole and the bushes fit perfectly on the axle, at least I think so. I'll check it again when I am home.

Comment: Do the teeth mesh properly with LEGO gears? If not, it is not LEGO.

Comment: @Kramii http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=x1307 for example doesn't mesh

Answer (score 7):

It is about the right size and shape to be the main shaft of this [wind-up motor](http://peeron.com/inv/parts/45721) from set [4093](http://peeron.com/inv/sets/4093-1):

[image]

Here's another view:

[image]

These pictures show the piece as white, but it might be a variant. I do not have one of these windups to take apart to check.

Comment: Could be a part of some other motor, too.